# Flyway command line tool doesn't prompt for user name and password

Tags: flyway

I do not want to configure user and password in `flyway.conf` and I read in the comments that it is not neccessary:

```
# User to use to connect to the database. Flyway will prompt you to enter it if not specified.
# flyway.user=

# Password to use to connect to the database. Flyway will prompt you to enter it if not specified.
# flyway.password=
```

but I get following error message:

```
ERROR: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource (jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://test-server/test) for user 'null': I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property.
```

[Documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/) also says:

> **Credentials**
>
> If you do not supply a database user and password via any of the means above, you will be prompted to enter them:

Is there anything more to do or is it a Bug (version 4.0)? With configured user name and password, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it is a bug and will be fixed in version 4.0.1, see [Issue 1245](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1245):

> There was a last minute bug that got introduced in #724 and that has now been fixed. This will be part of 4.0.1. You can of course build from source until then.